# Dreaded "Excel found unreadable content in..." message after adding custom icons

Tags: vba, excel, ribbon

I've been working on my Excel addin which makes use of the ribbon.  Everything is fine until I attempt to add some custom 16 x 16 icons.  Here in the office, we have Excel 2007, that is

**Microsoft Office Excel 2007 (12.0.6683.5002) SP3 MSO (12.0.6683.5000)**

My WinZip is

**WinZip 15.0 (9334)**

When I open my .xlam file as a Zip file, I currently have customUI\_rels and customUI\images subdirectories.  The contents of my customUI.xml.rels file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
<Relationship Id="nbinsert" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/image" Target="images/nbinsert.png" />
<Relationship Id="nbchange" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/image" Target="images/nbchange.png" />
<Relationship Id="nbdelete" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/image" Target="images/nbdelete.png" />
</Relationships>
```

The companion customUI\images subdirectory is empty.

At this stage, the file opens correctly.  The main customUI.XML does not even reference these new icons.  The relevant part looks like this:

```
  <box id="box01b" boxStyle="horizontal">
    <button id="bb00" onAction="NB.wrChange" imageMso="ChangeBinding"
      getScreentip="NB.wrChangeScreentip" getSupertip="NB.wrChangeSupertip" /> 
    <button id="bb01" onAction="NB.wrInsert" imageMso="RecurrenceEdit"
      getScreentip="NB.wrInsertScreentip" getSupertip="NB.wrInsertSupertip" />
    <button id="bb02" onAction="NB.wrDelete" imageMso="CancelRequest" 
      getScreentip="NB.wrDeleteScreentip" getSupertip="NB.wrDeleteSupertip" />
  </box>
```

I do not use the Custom UI Editor, all XML is either hand coded or generated.

Once the icons are in, I would have to change, for example imageMso="ChangeBinding" to image="nbchange".  At least, that's what I would have hoped.

Then I copy the new icons, three .png files, into the images subdirectory and save and rename back to the .xlam file.  When it attempts to open the addin, Excel complains with the aforementioned error message.  Consequently, after I remove these offending icons, the addin opens correctly.

In Word 2010, I had no problems having extra, unreferenced icons hanging around in my images subdirectory.  Also, references to nonexistent icons in the XML resulted in the icons simply not displaying, but never an error.

Is there anything special about custom icons which needs to be observed for them to work, for example, no transparency?  Or is the addin file just so fragile and sensitive?  Or should I try a later WinZip version?

These icons were originally found on www.iconfinder.com then made smaller (originally 32 x 32, then reduced to 16 x 16) using MS Paint.  I also tried changing them to 24 colour .BMP icons and had the same problem.

I had custom icons in Excel 2010 (copied from the same place, but 32 x 32) which worked without any fuss.

Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the following statement to the file named `[Content_Types].xml`:

```
<Default Extension="png" ContentType="image/png" />
```

[position of [Content_Types].xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3U1WV.png)

[content of [Content_Types].xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBAO8.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).